# create custom webdatasets for RL

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, webdataset

I want to create a custom dataset with the webdatasets package for reinforcement learning. The structure is as follows for each step.

step : image, state, action, reward, new_image, new_state

I create a code to explain my method :

```
import numpy as np
import webdataset as wds
from PIL import Image

# example data
image_step0 = np.ones([472, 472, 3]) 
image_step1 = np.ones([472, 472, 3]) * 0
image_step2 = np.ones([472, 472, 3]) * 0.5

state_step1 = np.array([4, 5, 6])
action_step1 = np.array([0, 5, 0])
reward_step1 = int(4)
new_state_step1 = np.array([4, 10, 6])

state_step2 = np.array([4, 10, 6])
action_step2 = np.array([1, 0, 0])
reward_step2 = int(11)
new_state_step2 = np.array([5, 10, 6])

# Write the dataset
sink = wds.TarWriter("dataset.tar")

# Write data for step 1
sink.write(
    {
        "__key__": "step1",
        "metadata.json": {
            "state": state_step1.tolist(),
            "action": action_step1.tolist(),
            "reward": reward_step1,
            "new_state": new_state_step1.tolist(),
        },
        "image.png": image_step0,
        "next_image.png": image_step1,
    }
)

# Write data for step 2
sink.write(
    {
        "__key__": "step2",
        "metadata.json": {
            "state": state_step2.tolist(),
            "action": action_step2.tolist(),
            "reward": reward_step2,
            "new_state": new_state_step2.tolist(),
        },
        "image.png": image_step1,
        "next_image.png": image_step2,
    }
)

sink.close()
```

that create a dataset like that:

```
dataset/step1.image.png
dataset/step1.metadata.json
dataset/step1.next_image.png
dataset/step2.image.png
dataset/step2.metadata.json
dataset/step2.next_image.png
```

but "step1.next_image.png" is the same image as "step2.image.png"

Do you have another way to create a dataset without this duplication problem to reduce the tar size?